# JavaFX primaryStage.close() from method

Tags: java, methods, javafx, stage

I currently have some code that makes a button in the `primaryStage` that spawns a new stage.  My goal is to have the button close the stage it's on using the `setOnMouseClicked` method right after launching the new one.  Here is how it's currently setup:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    setPlayBtn();

}

private void setPlayBtn() {
    play = new ImageView(new Image(BugWars.class.getResourceAsStream("images/play-btn.png")));
    play.setFitHeight(50);
    play.setFitWidth(50);
    play.setX(375);
    play.setY(375);
    play.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            setGame(); // This creates the new stage.
            primaryStage.close();

        }
    });
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.  Netbeans complains that it can't find the symbol. It thinks it's a variable.  I'm sure it's something stupid, but any help referencing the `primaryStage` would be appreciated.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've worked around the problem by simply making the `PlayBtn` instatiate inside of the `start()` method that(I believe) creates `primaryStage` and then making `primaryStage` `final`.  I don't know why this works, but it does.